# problem with converting .tflite model to .h using xxd -i model.tflite > model.h

Tags: tensorflow, esp32, tensorflow-lite, file-conversion, tflite

when ever i try to convert my TensorFlow lite model from .tflite to .h model the file size before conversion is 1.9mb and after conversion its 11.5mb and I need to deploy it on esp32 but I don't know what am gonna to do that since the file size is 11.5mb and esp32 storage size is 4mb.

is there any other way to convert without increasing the size ?

Comment: What matters is the size once it’s compiled and linked, not the size of the .h file. Have you tried actually building it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.